# Generating strings combining letter and number sequences in R

Tags: r

How can i generate this vector in R:

`x <- c("R11", "R12", "R13", "R21", "R22", "R23", "R31",....)` until `R7xx` for a set of six letters `(R, S, D, A, B, X)`?

and so on? Without actually typing it.

Comment: `expand.grid` might be useful to look at.

Comment: What exactly is the final value `R7xx`?

Comment: Its  basically all combinations of (A,B,D,R,S,X):(1:7):(1:3) in a single vector. So, its LETTER73.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
m <- expand.grid(c('A','B','D','R','X'),1:7,1:3)
apply(m,1,paste0,collapse = "")
```

One way to force a specific, non-alphabetic ordering would be to explicitly indicate it using a factor and then order the results from `expand.grid`:

```
m <- expand.grid(factor(c('R','A','B','D','X'),levels = c('R','A','B','D','X')),
                 1:7,
                 1:3)
m <- m[order(m[,1],m[,2],m[,3]),]
```

And then run the `apply` line as before.

Comment: +1, a slight variation would be `do.call(paste0, expand.grid(c("A","B","D","R","X"), 1:7, 1:3))` though I don't know which might perform better

Comment: This is already very close, thank you! however the ordering is now "R11", "R21", "R31" and so. Is there a way to reorder m?

Comment: @nouse I presume the 2nd and 3rd places should be ordered numerically. In what order should the letters fall? R first, and then....?

Comment: R11 R12 R13 R21 R22 R23 and so on

Comment: @nouse I was sort of asking what order the letters _after_ R come in, but hopefully my edit above provides enough information for you to take it from here.

Answer (score 2):

`expand.grid` begins with the first argument to circle. In case this should be the opposite way, the arguments to `expand.grid` need to be given reverse and its result needs to be reversed again.

```
do.call(paste0, rev(expand.grid(1:3, 1:7, c("R", "S", "D", "A", "B", "X"))))
#  [1] "R11" "R12" "R13" "R21" "R22" "R23" "R31" "R32" "R33" "R41" "R42" "R43"
# [13] "R51" "R52" "R53" "R61" "R62" "R63" "R71" "R72" "R73" "S11" "S12" "S13"
# [25] "S21" "S22" "S23" "S31" "S32" "S33" "S41" "S42" "S43" "S51" "S52" "S53"
# [37] "S61" "S62" "S63" "S71" "S72" "S73" "D11" "D12" "D13" "D21" "D22" "D23"
# [49] "D31" "D32" "D33" "D41" "D42" "D43" "D51" "D52" "D53" "D61" "D62" "D63"
# [61] "D71" "D72" "D73" "A11" "A12" "A13" "A21" "A22" "A23" "A31" "A32" "A33"
# [73] "A41" "A42" "A43" "A51" "A52" "A53" "A61" "A62" "A63" "A71" "A72" "A73"
# [85] "B11" "B12" "B13" "B21" "B22" "B23" "B31" "B32" "B33" "B41" "B42" "B43"
# [97] "B51" "B52" "B53" "B61" "B62" "B63" "B71" "B72" "B73" "X11" "X12" "X13"
#[109] "X21" "X22" "X23" "X31" "X32" "X33" "X41" "X42" "X43" "X51" "X52" "X53"
#[121] "X61" "X62" "X63" "X71" "X72" "X73"
```

In case the output should be a `factor` `expand.grid` with `interaction` could be used.

```
interaction(rev(expand.grid(1:3, 1:7, c("R", "S", "D", "A", "B", "X"))), sep="")
#  [1] R11 R12 R13 R21 R22 R23 R31 R32 R33 R41 R42 R43 R51 R52 R53 R61 R62 R63
# [19] R71 R72 R73 S11 S12 S13 S21 S22 S23 S31 S32 S33 S41 S42 S43 S51 S52 S53
# [37] S61 S62 S63 S71 S72 S73 D11 D12 D13 D21 D22 D23 D31 D32 D33 D41 D42 D43
# [55] D51 D52 D53 D61 D62 D63 D71 D72 D73 A11 A12 A13 A21 A22 A23 A31 A32 A33
# [73] A41 A42 A43 A51 A52 A53 A61 A62 A63 A71 A72 A73 B11 B12 B13 B21 B22 B23
# [91] B31 B32 B33 B41 B42 B43 B51 B52 B53 B61 B62 B63 B71 B72 B73 X11 X12 X13
#[109] X21 X22 X23 X31 X32 X33 X41 X42 X43 X51 X52 X53 X61 X62 X63 X71 X72 X73
#126 Levels: R11 S11 D11 A11 B11 X11 R21 S21 D21 A21 B21 X21 R31 S31 D31 ... X73
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- 10
i<- 0
abc <- array()
xyz <- array()
words <- c('R','S','D','A','B','X')


for(j in 1:6) {
for(i in 1:7) {
abc <- paste(words[j], (x*i + 1):(x*i + 3), sep = "")
xyz <- c(xyz, abc)
}
}

xyz
[1] NA    "R11" "R12" "R13" "R21" "R22" "R23" "R31" "R32" "R33" "R41" "R42" "R43" "R51" "R52" "R53"
[17] "R61" "R62" "R63" "R71" "R72" "R73" "S11" "S12" "S13" "S21" "S22" "S23" "S31" "S32" "S33" "S41"
[33] "S42" "S43" "S51" "S52" "S53" "S61" "S62" "S63" "S71" "S72" "S73" "D11" "D12" "D13" "D21" "D22"
[49] "D23" "D31" "D32" "D33" "D41" "D42" "D43" "D51" "D52" "D53" "D61" "D62" "D63" "D71" "D72" "D73"
[65] "A11" "A12" "A13" "A21" "A22" "A23" "A31" "A32" "A33" "A41" "A42" "A43" "A51" "A52" "A53" "A61"
[81]"A62" "A63" "A71" "A72" "A73" "B11" "B12" "B13" "B21" "B22" "B23" "B31" "B32" "B33" "B41" "B42"
[97] "B43" "B51" "B52" "B53" "B61" "B62" "B63" "B71" "B72" "B73" "X11" "X12" "X13" "X21" "X22" "X23"
[113] "X31" "X32" "X33" "X41" "X42" "X43" "X51" "X52" "X53" "X61" "X62" "X63" "X71" "X72" "X73"
```

`NA` gets generated as first value. To remove that `NA` you can use,

```
xyz <- xyz[-1]
```